# Where is the "search" element in the coding?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

Realized there is a **`search`** element but could not find the HTML code.

It was there when tried to inspect the page. is it part of the AJAX component? what is it called?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head runat="server">
  <title>Carousel Slider</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#GridView1").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 350px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
      <h4 class="text-capitalize text-center">Bootstrap Carousel Image Slider with database in asp.net</h4>
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <div class="carousel-item <%#GetActiveClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
                <img alt="<%#Eval(" ImageName ")%>" src="<%#Eval(" ImagePath ")%>" />
              </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
        <div class="card-header bg-primary">
          <strong class="card-title text-uppercase text-white">carousel Slider Images</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <button type="button" style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0" data-target="#AddImage" data-toggle="modal">Add New Image</button>
          <div class="modal fade" id="AddImage">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Carousel Image Slider</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Choose Slider Image</label>
                        <div class="custom-file">
                          <asp:FileUpload ID="SliderFileUpload" runat="server" CssClass="custom-file-input" />
                          <label class="custom-file-label"></label>
                        </div>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn btn-primary rounded-0" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger rounded-0" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HeaderStyle-CssClass="bg-primary text-white" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="ImageName" HeaderText="Image Name" />
              <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="ImagePath" ControlStyle-CssClass="img-thumbnail" ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="60" HeaderText="Image" />
            </Columns>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>No Record Available <b>Click Add New Image to add Record</b></EmptyDataTemplate>
          </asp:GridView>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard dataTable component, see example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html)

In your code dataTable initializes in this line:

```
$("#GridView1").prepend($("<thead</thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable();
```